# Jump to own cursor in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

If multiple people are editing a spreadsheet, one just has to click the avatar of another person present to jump to their cursor.

**Is there any way to quickly jump to my own cursor?** Fox example, when scrolling around to find some data, it's easy to get lost in a long table, but there's no easy way to get back - except for remembering the cell coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the arrow keys to move the focus one cell then again to return to the original cell, i.e. right arrow, left arrow.